# What could be causing this weird regular expression behaviour in node.js?

Tags: regex, node.js, v8

Executing the following code, takes forever:

```
"Hello there, very best wishes, from Syria...".match(/^((?:, |[\w ]+)+)$/)
```

while executing the following, takes a little bit less than ever, but a little bit more than ten seconds!

```
"Hello there, best wishes, from Syria...".match(/^((?:, |[\w ]+)+)$/)
```

...and then it returns `null`

Tried on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit machine, Archlinux 32-bit server and a Debian Wheezy 32-bit server, all of which running node v0.10.18.

---

**EDIT:** Apparently the behaviour is inherited from V8, the same code makes Chrome's console hang, and mongo shell (that uses V8 as well) hang too!

Comment: This does appear to be a bug and would probably be worth posting on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/v8-users) or [as an issue](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/list). v8 seems to be fine with either `$` in the pattern or `...` in the strings, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure what's happening here is [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). For example on my machine:

- For 39 chars in "`Hello there, best wishes, from Syria...`" it takes around 13-14 seconds.
- For 40 chars in "`Hello there, vbest wishes, from Syria...`" it takes 27-28 seconds.
- For 41 chars in "`Hello there, vebest wishes, from Syria...`" it takes 56 seconds.

You can see the time taken increases exponentially. To explain how regex engine matches string via backtracking, I will quote the example from above link. It applies regex `(x+x+)+y` on string `xxxxxxxxxxy` :

> Let's see what happens when you apply this regex to xxxxxxxxxxy. The
>   first x+ will match all 10 x characters. The second x+ fails. The
>   first x+ then backtracks to 9 matches, and the second one picks up the
>   remaining x. The group has now matched once. The group repeats, but
>   fails at the first x+. Since one repetition was sufficient, the group
>   matches. y matches y and an overall match is found. The regex is
>   declared functional, the code is shipped to the customer, and his
>   computer explodes. Almost.
>
> The above regex turns ugly when the y is missing from the subject
>   string. When y fails, the regex engine backtracks. The group has one
>   iteration it can backtrack into. The second x+ matched only one x, so
>   it can't backtrack. But the first x+ can give up one x. The second x+
>   promptly matches xx. The group again has one iteration, fails the next
>   one, and the y fails. Backtracking again, the second x+ now has one
>   backtracking position, reducing itself to match x. The group tries a
>   second iteration. The first x+ matches but the second is stuck at the
>   end of the string. Backtracking again, the first x+ in the group's
>   first iteration reduces itself to 7 characters. The second x+ matches
>   xxx. Failing y, the second x+ is reduced to xx and then x. Now, the
>   group can match a second iteration, with one x for each x+. But this
>   (7,1),(1,1) combination fails too. So it goes to (6,4) and then
>   (6,2)(1,1) and then (6,1),(2,1) and then (6,1),(1,2) and then I think
>   you start to get the drift.

See [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html) page from Jeff on regex performance, which uses the same example. So moral of the story : don't just match stuff, improve the regex. When nesting repetition operators, make absolutely sure that there is only one way to match the same match. For the example I quoted `xx+y` works better. And for your regex the answer Esailija gave will work much better `/^([\w, ]+)$/`

Answer (score 1):

This regex is equivalent and runs fast:

```
/^([\w, ]+)$/
```

The problem is with your regex, not V8. Other engines just report no match after trying it a while (which is not necessarily the correct result), V8 tries to get the correct result even if it takes forever. You need to take care how you write regex, it's just like any other code - it doesn't magically protect from programmer mistakes.